# How to pass ng-model from directive to template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given the following directive defnintion

```
app.directive('myDirective', () => (
    {
        restrict: 'E'
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<div id='wrapper'><input ngChange="change" /></div>'
        scope: {change: '='},
        link: ...
    }
))
```

If I use it like this

```
<my-directive change="change" ng-model="myModel" />
```

How do I pass `ng-model` from `my-directive` to the `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one-way `<` for binding inputs and [$setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue) for setting output:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        template:
            `<div id='wrapper'>
                 <input ng-change="change(inputValue)" ng-model="inputValue" />
             </div>`,                  
        scope: {inputValue: '<ngModel'},
        link: postLink              
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.change = function(value) {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
        };
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
<form name="form1">
    <my-directive name="item1" ng-model="myModel" ng-change="func1()">
    </my-directive>
</form>
```

The `ng-change` directive will be added automatically by the `ngModelController`.

The AngularJS framework will put the `ngModelController` API on scope as `$scope.form1.item1`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#)
- [AngularJS ngFormController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: To render the value, you need to add `ngModel.$render();`